# Relations in Laravel with dynamic attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent, attributes, e-commerce

Imagine in ecommerce attributes and values. Ex: size (S,M,L), weight (100,200), color (red,green,blue).

Each of variations has own price:

S, 100, red : 32$

S, 200, red : 18$

S, 100, green : 25$

etc...

Administrator has possibility CRUD attributes and values in CMS. Administrator can select created attributes and values and **insert price**.

Do you know the way to save this prices in DB?

Comment: Hi :) I think this question is more about database schema than laravel, you can do that in a very different ways, having multiple tables relationships with N-N relations, you can save also those attributes in a JSON column too